# How does msbuild resolve assembly from a multi-framework nuget package?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, nuget-package

I have a solution with a console app `ConsoleApp-net461` that references a library `ClassLibrary-net452`.

Both projects reference a multi-framework nuget package `NuGetPackage-net452-net461`.

When I build, I end up with the nuget package's net461 dll in the output folder. At runtime, I am getting errors like:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'ClassA'. 
Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.
```

I am suspecting this is because my `ClassLibrary-net452` ends up having a dependency on the nuget package dll with the net461 framework.

Is this normal behavior? What are the best ways to ensure the net452 dll is resolved from the nuget package? BindingRedirects don't seem to let you choose a target framework.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure this will work, but might be worth trying:

(Relies on using SDK csproj format, [this](https://duanenewman.net/blog/post/using-prism-with-xamarin-forms-and-gtk/) link might work for packages.config, but I know less about the area.)

It looks like what you want is something like [this](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1791#issuecomment-436179014). However the dotnet/SDK team haven't got round to implementing it yet.

The suggested work around is:
- Grab the dll path from your package reference
- Tell the package reference to not copy compile assets (dlls).
- Use the dll path to generate a similar path for a non-package reference that redirects to the Net452 version of the package.

Explanatory links [here](https://duanenewman.net/blog/post/forcing-a-specific-target-platform-with-packagereference/) and [here](https://duanenewman.net/blog/post/a-better-way-to-override-references-with-packagereference/).

Summary is that your csproj should contain something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="*MyPackageName*" ExcludeAssets="Compile" GeneratePathProperty="true">
        <Version>x.y.z</Version>
    </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="*NameYouWantToGiveThisReference(suggest dll name)*">
  <HintPath>$(Pkg*MyPackageName*)lib\net452\*DLLname*.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Everything surrounded by ** needs to be named according to whatever your projects are actually called.
The two *MyPackageName*s must match up (with the caveat that all "."s in the first one should be replaced with "_" in the second one).